# Extracting parts of CSV data constructed in different ways in the same file using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
Kill #,Timestamp,Bot,Weapon,TTK,Shots,Hits,Accuracy,Damage Done,Damage Possible,Efficiency,Cheated
1,17:56:13:353,TileFrenzyStrafing Cube,TileFrenzy Challenge,0.308s,2,1,0.5,100,400,0.25,false
2,17:56:13:672,TileFrenzyStrafing Cube,TileFrenzy Challenge,0s,1,1,1,100,200,0.5,false
...

Weapon,Shots,Hits,Damage Done,Damage Possible,,Sens Scale,Horiz Sens,Vert Sens,FOV,Hide Gun,Crosshair,Crosshair Scale,Crosshair Color,ADS Sens,ADS Zoom Scale
TileFrenzy Challenge,101,81,8100.0,20200.0,

Kills:,81
Deaths:,0
Fight Time:,6.31
Avg TTK:,0.078
Damage Done:,8100.0
Damage Taken:,0.0
Midairs:,0
Midaired:,0
Directs:,0
Directed:,0
Distance Traveled:,0.0
Score:,64.960396
Scenario:,Tile Frenzy - Strafing - 01
Hash:,de995d9d66c7950c6dcb779ce6bc50a0
Game Version:,2.0.0.2

Input Lag:,0
Max FPS (config):,300.0
Sens Scale:,Quake/Source
Horiz Sens:,1.46
Vert Sens:,1.46
FOV:,90.0
Hide Gun:,false
Crosshair:,plus.png
Crosshair Scale:,1.0
Crosshair Color:,FFFFFF
```

The data in this CSV file is first constructed with an undetermined amount of rows with headers which I would want to extract as a DataFrame object using pandas. I then also want to extract the part of the CSV that gives information about kills, deaths, and fight time, etc as a separate DataFrame object.

If I just naively try to use `pd.read_csv()` I get and error as the row length is not constant throughout the CSV file. I have tried many solutions which include using `error_bad_lines=False` and setting a maximum row length using `name=list(range(N))` but none of them help my case as that gives me a single DataFrame object that is hard to parse in the ways I want to extract the data. I also tried using `nrows=` but as the first part of the file will have an undetermined amount of rows, this won't solve my problem.

I feel like there is a simple way to just split the CSV file by each empty line or something similar but I had no results that would work smoothly with the structure of this file. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the last 29 rows of the file-snippet you pasted are not real-csv entries.

You could try using the parameter `skipfooter` ([pandas.read_csv() manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('filename.csv',skipfooter=29)
```

EDIT:
Your file snippet contains various format-styles

- 1) lines 1-4: typical ".csv" style. Line 1 is the header of the columns read-in by pd.read_csv. (I guess that the dots mark a continuation of data in your file). In order to read the data as a table - pandas.DataFrame - the last lines have to be omitted.
- 2) lines 5-6: list of strings. Maybe some ingame settings?
- 3) lines 7-33: key and value pairs similar to python dictionaries, a typical structure for the yaml-format.

Here is an example for parsing the last 29-lines to a python dictionary:

```
#read all lines in input file
lines = [l for l in open("filename.csv").readlines()];

#create dictionary
mydict={}
for line in lines[-29:]:              #last lines only
    dlm=':,';                         #specify delimiter 
    if dlm in line:                   #check if valid dictionary pair
        key,value=line.split(dlm);    
        value=value.replace('\n',''); 

        #string conversion
        try  :
            mydict[key]=float(value);
        except :
            mydict[key]=value;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked well to get all the data in the first part of the file consistently. Pandas is able to read the remaining data if I use `skiprows=` to remove the first part in a well-constructed manner but I don't have a clue how to extract the other block of data I am looking for.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the information. Just reading the last lines could be done like: linesTail = [l for l in open("filename.csv").readlines()][-29:];
On a side note, the format of the last lines is similar to a python dictionary (key:value) or the ".yaml" file format.

Comment: Your edit worked perfectly for my case. I was stuck with having to use pandas to solve all of this but it doesn't seem like I have to. Thank you so much for your help!